# SQL Plus error using sdeversion

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql

I'm new to SQL Plus and I have a question. I've created several versions of a feature class located on a SDE database. I want to use ArcSDE Administration Commands found [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/support_files/datamgmt/sdeversion.htm) but I'm getting an error message. After logging into SQL Plus here's what happens:

```
SQL> sdeversion -o describe -V SDE.DEFAULT -u ** -p **
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "sdeversion..." - rest of line ignored.
```

As you can see I attempt to describe the Default version and get an error.

Does anyone know how I can overcome that SP2-0734 error?

I have Oracle 11.2 on my machine and my Oracle database is 10g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an exe and should exist in an sde bin someplace: SDEHOME or a USB drive that you keep with you at all times (*or maybe not*). You don't use it from inside SQLPlus.

It lives with these files:
[image]

[image]